# How to Customize Button's Size?

Tags: user-interface, button, windows-phone-8.1

I have problem to customize the buttons' size in my stack panel. I made one experiment with Rectangle, it looks perfect, here is the code in the XAML:

```xml
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Rectangle Width="170" Height="170" Fill="Bisque" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,0,0,0">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="Azure" />
            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="Azure" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>
                        
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="Tomato" />
            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="Azure" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
                    
</StackPanel>
```

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

But, when I remove those Rectangles to Buttons,
like these in the XAML:

```xml
<Button x:Name="Btn2" >
</Button>
<Button x:Name="Btn3" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="11,0,0,0"  >
</Button>
```

it looks not what i want:

[image]

I can't resize those 2 buttons. How to get a quick solution for this?

Comment: Maybe changing button's *MinWidth* property will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buttons in WP8.1 have deafault minimum width - *MinWidth* property - try changing it and it should help.

A side note - consider using *Grid* panel instead of *StackPanel* for positioning elements. If you define some *Rows* and *Columns*, your app should scale correctly when used on different devices.